# Dart make sure optional boolean in class is not null

Tags: class, flutter, dart, null

Since it's an optional value, it will sometimes be null, so how can I avoid it throwing an error? Is this the only way to do it?

```
class QText extends StatelessWidget {
  QText(this.text, this.size, [this.bold]);

  final String text;
  final double size;
  bool bold;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bold = (bold == null) ? false : bold;
    return Whatever..
  }
}
```

I'd like to do this but of course it doesn't work:

```
class QText extends StatelessWidget {
  QText(this.text, this.size, [this.bold]);

  final String text;
  final double size;
  final bool bold ?? false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Whatever..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the fields are final try passing the default during constructor initialization.

Also add an `assert` statement to make sure it's never initialized to `null`.

Example:

```
class QText extends StatelessWidget {
  QText(this.text, this.size, [this.bold = false]) : assert(bold != null);

  final String text;
  final double size;
  final bool bold;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't use assert as it is ignored in production: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert

Answer (score 4):

For now, all types in Dart are nullable. Even with a default value, someone can explicitly pass `null` as argument. If you want to be absolutely certain that the value is not `null`, you must guard all ways to set the value. In the original example the `bold` variable was public and not final, which means that you must also guard the setter.

Example with final variable:

```
class QText extends StatelessWidget {
  QText(this.text, this.size, [bool bold]) : this.bold = bold ?? false;

  final String text;
  final double size;
  final bool bold;
  ...
}
```

Example with settable `bold`:

```
class QText extends StatelessWidget {
  QText(this.text, this.size, [bool bold]) : this.bold = bold ?? false;

  final String text;
  final double size;
  bool _bold;

  bool get bold => _bold;
  void set bold(bool bold) { this._bold = bold ?? false; }
  ...
}
```

You can use a default value, but it doesn't buy you anything security-wise. It is useful as documentation, though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your default value for variable inside the constructor:

Like below:

```
QText(this.text, this.size, [this.bold = false]): assert(bold != null,"bold cannot be null.");
```

If nothing is passed in `bold` variable then it will take default value as `false`.

**EDIT**

You can use the assertion to prevent user to pass null, you can also print a message if assertion fails.

```
assert(bold != null,"bold cannot be null.")
```

Comment: Really? So you can do that just like in Javascript. That's cool. Don't know why I didn't even try that lol.

Comment: This does not prevent a caller from explicitly passing `null` as an argument.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the question is soon outdated as the language will prevent null in that case pretty soon. Null safety is already available in the dev channel.

more info: https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-sound-null-safety-defd2216a6f3